# jQuery-Based Dropdown Shows Gap Outside of Firefox

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have created a very simple autocomplete dropdown widget in jQuery, which you can apply to `input` elements. It works great, but for some reason, the dropdown list shows a gap between the `input` and the list in browsers other than Firefox (tested in IE, Safari and Chrome).

I've mocked this up in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMCzJ/3/), to demonstrate the problem, only to find that it worked fine in all browsers... That was until I unticked the "Normalized CSS" option. Then the gap reappeared in IE, etc., but it still works fine in Firefox. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

This is clearly thus a CSS problem. However, I can't for the life of me work out where the problem lies. I've had a look at jsFiddle's `normalize.css` and tried a few things from there (mostly setting the padding and margins of various selectors to 0px), but I can't get it to work! Any ideas on how I can change my CSS so that the gap disappears in all browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get rid of the gap simply by setting the top margin on your div.popup ul to 0px.

```
div.popup ul {
list-style: none;
background: red;
padding: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
}
```